# Does my Betta have dropsy?

Tags: health, betta

[image]

Hi,
I’ve had a betta and some tetras in a 30litre tank for about 5 months. Everything’s been good, they all get along, eating fine, not fighting and such, until this morning I noticed that my betta’s ‘neck’ area is swollen. He’s still acting normal and lively, his scales aren’t like a pinecone and he’s eating fine so nothings changed in terms of behaviour, just in appearance but even then I could be imagining things. All the other fish are fine. I’m just wondering whether I should start to treat him or if this will just make him worse if he doesn’t have the condition. I change water regularly enough and test the ph/nitrate and try in general to take good care of my fish. Any thoughts as to how I should proceed?

Thanks,
Emma

Comment: It's difficult to tell from your picture because the area in question is in shadow. What are you most recent readings for Ammonia / Nitrite / Nitrate? How much do you feed and how often do you change the water?

Comment: My ammonia was 0 according to the kit I have, and then the nitrate I think was 5?  I change half the water every week and then do a full change whenever I think the tank needs it which is probably every 2 or 3 weeks. I feed the fish to the point where they wont eat any more